# Xcode error: "Undefined symbols for architecture x86_64: "_addStudent", referenced from: _main in main.o"

Tags: c, xcode, linker

I'm new to Xcode, and when I try to create a linked list, these errors happen but I don't know how figure those out, can you help me?
[image: errors]

[image: main.c]

[image: sl.h]

[image: sl.c]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is because function definition for `addStudent` is missing. Provide body for the function and the error will vansih. I see body for `addList` and I assume this is actually `addStudent` but with a wrong name

Comment: show me how addStudent function definition looks now

Comment: Sorry, I don't understand what means that it actually looks. In addStudent function, I malloc a new node--"student", and give it named and *next

Comment: It is in the last picture

Comment: Can you see it now?

Comment: Sorry to trouble you, I figure this out, it is because I haven't malloced the top of the list